# Pass parameter to page, data not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

I have a navigation component where I'm passing a parameter to another page, the parameter is getting passed, however, the data in the dropdown is not updating for the passed ID:

nav:

```
<Link to='/service/ServiceAppointment/${car.Make}'> { serviceAppointment } </Link>
```

appointment page:

```
const ScheduleAppointment = () => {
 const { id } = useParams();
 
console.log (id);  //I can see the ID passed to the page in the console
 
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id); //the ID is not there
    scheduleAppointment(id);   
  });

  const Appointment= () => {
     //call to API for open dates
     //the ID never gets here

  }
}
```

Router:

```
<Route exact path='/service/appointment/:id' component={ ScheduleAppointment }   />
```

how can I get the appointment page to change when a new ID is passed to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies argument of `useEffect` is `useEffect(callback, dependencies)`

Let's explore side effects and runs:

**Not provided: the side-effect runs after every rendering.**

```
 import { useEffect } from 'react';
    
    function MyComponent() {
      useEffect(() => {
        // Runs after EVERY rendering
      });  
    }
```

**An empty array []: the side-effect runs once after the initial rendering.**

```
 import { useEffect } from 'react';
    
    function MyComponent() {
      useEffect(() => {
        // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
      }, []);
    }
```

**Has props or state values `[prop1, prop2, ..., state1, state2]`: the side-effect runs only when any dependency value changes.**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent({ prop }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
    // and after every rendering ONLY IF `prop` or `state` changes
  }, [prop, state]);
}
```

in your case try this way

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id); //the ID is not there
    scheduleAppointment(id);   
},[id]);
```

Comment: This worked. Adding [id] worked, thanks: useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id); //the ID is not there
    scheduleAppointment(id);   
},[id]);

Answer (score 0):

Please update the below link instead of your code

```
<Link to=`/service/ServiceAppointment/${car.Make}`> { serviceAppointment } </Link>
```

I hope it will work for you! Thanks.

Comment: That's what I have, for some reason the ${car.Make} showed up green on the page